# О - частица или междометие?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, егэ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как определить, когда о обособляется перед обращением, а когда нет? На решу егэ много таких заданий, и там только написано, что обособление будет зависеть от того, какой частью речи является о, но чёткого объяснения, как определить, чем оно является,нет.

Comment: О — это междометие и только междометие (ну, и предлог ещë). И оно можел выделяться, а может и нет.

Comment: @Максим По словарю да, междометие. А почему не частица? Какая разница-то?  Многие называют частицей, например  https://popravilam.com/blog/015-chastica-o.html    http://gramota.ru/forum/veche/12201/

Comment: При слитном написании О усиливает значение слова, а это функция частицы. Конечно, нужно все по правилам, но и причину знать хотелось бы. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_879

Comment: Я спрашивала, когда о обособляется. На прикреплённом фото показано два случая, и в комментариях написано, что в одном случае это междометие, а в другом - частица с риторическим вопросом. В первом случае запятая есть, а в другом нет.

Comment: Ну да, все так и считают. Если не обособляется, то частица, а междометие обособляется. Я думаю, что на форуме вам дадут ответы)  Интересно послушать именно объяснение.

Answer (score 1):

**ТЕОРИЯ**

**(1)**  **ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ:**

О, **межд.**

1. Усиливает **экспрессивность** высказывания. О, я совершенно спокоен! О, какая красота! О, поедем в горы. О, это скучная история... / (**в риторич. вопросе и восклиц.**). О! сколько мне ещё мучиться! О Россия! * О Муза! Ты была мне другом (Некрасов).

**2. (при утвердительных или отриц. сл.).** **Усиливает** утверждение или отрицание. О нет, я не поеду. О, никогда! О да, это замечательно! Ты довольна? - О да!

3. Выражает какое-л. **сильное чувство** (чаще **боль, страдание, тревогу, отчаяние**). О, как больно! О, если б ты знал. О, отлично! / (с межд. сл.). О Господи! О Боже! О чёрт! О дьявол!

**(2)** **КОГДА ОБОСОБЛЯТЬ ИЛИ НЕ ОБОСОБЛЯТЬ?**

**Обособление:**

**Усилительное значение** (экспрессия **высказывания**): О, какая красота! О, поедем в горы. О, это скучная история...

Выражение **сильного чувства** (разного!): О, как больно! О, если б ты знал. О, отлично!

**Нет обособления** (**усиление экспрессии**)

Риторический вопрос или восклицание, в том числе при **обращении**:  *О! сколько мне ещё мучиться! О Россия!  О Муза! Ты была мне другом.*

**ВЫВОД**

(1) Определенность есть только **при выражении чувства,** при этом  хорошо бы уточнить это чувство **по контексту**. Междометие обособляется, что можно определить **по интонации**.

(2) А вот с риторическими **обращениями и восклицаниями** определенности нет, там возможны оба варианта. Определяем **по контексту и по интонации.**

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

(1) **Выражение глубокого чувства** (боль, презрение, отчаяние): «О, недостойный!

Мне **обособление** больше нравится. Но тексту Наина уже достаточно **взволнована**, чтобы выразить свои чувства. А риторическое **обращение** чаще используется в высоком (**позитивном**) смысле.

(2) **Выражение чувства** (сожаление): Увы, сама себя вини;

(3) **Риторическое восклицание,** оценка ситуации: о позор!

(4) **Обращение:** Но трепещи, девичий вор!

Можно придумать **свои примеры**))

**Обращение**: *О Вера, я так ждал тебя, а ты не пришла. О, Вера!*

**Риторика:**  О, напрасны все мои мечты! О любовь!

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**[Из Интернета](https://studfile.net/preview/5582251/page:20/):** **Риторическое обращение** – фигура, представляющая собой условное обращение к предметам и явлениям, которое используется для привлечения внимания к предмету речи слушателей и читателей. **Риторическое восклицание** – эмоционально окрашенное предложение с восклицательной интонацией.Чаще всего риторические восклицания встречаются в художественной речи, публицистике и ораторской прозе.

Answer (score 1):

> **Как определить**, когда ***о*** обособляется перед обращением, а когда нет?

**По интонационному выделению/невыделению** этого «о» при прочтении текста.

Если «о» не имеет самостоятельного ударения, то обособлять его не следует. Если же «о» ударно, а после него имеется пауза, то его следует обособить.

Вот как рекомендует различать междометия ***о, ах, а*** и омонимичные им частицы [**«Полный академический справочник» под ред.  Лопатина**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=129#pp129):

> **§ 103… Примечание.** Омонимичные частицы и междометия (*о, ах, а*) различаются следующим образом: частица имеет усилительное значение и от обращения интонационно не отделяется (не имеет самостоятельного ударения); напротив, междометия интонационно самостоятельны, ударны, после них имеется пауза. Ср.: ***О поле мое заветное**, ты сейчас отдыхаешь после жатвы* (Айтм.) — ***О, ветер! О, снежные бури!*** (Бл.).

Проблема в том, что приведённые в задании строки из «Руслана и Людмилы» могут быть прочитаны двояко: и с ударением на «о» плюс с паузой после него — и без ударения на «о». И оба варианта будут правильны.

К примеру, в первом издании «Руслана и Людмилы» [**Руслан и Людмила : поэма в шести песнях. / соч. А. Пушкина. - Санктпетербург : в Типографии Н. Греча, 1820**] запятой после «о» не было:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не было её и во втором издании [**Руслан и Людмила : Поэма Александра Пушкина. - 2-е изд., испр. и умнож. - Санкт-Петербург : тип. Деп. нар. прос., 1828**].

Не было и в ряде более поздних изданий.

Отсутствует запятая после «о» и в некоторых современных изданиях. См., например, [**Руслан и Людмила : поэма : [для среднего школьного возраста : 12+] / А. С. Пушкин ; художники Б. Дехтерёв и Д. Поляков. - Москва : Детская литература, 2019**]:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правда, печатались и раньше, продолжают печататься и сейчас разбираемые нами строки и с запятой после «о». Какой из этих вариантов лучше — с запятой или без – думаю, определяется вкусовыми предпочтениями издателей.

Во всяком случае, ни один из этих вариантов правилам не противоречит.

---

**P.S.**

В противовес вот этому пояснению в задании:

> Зпт 1 для выделения междометия, стоящего **НЕ перед риторическим обращением**; это не «О море»…

— можно привести пример из Куприна, вошедший [в **«Справочник по пунктуации»**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_879) Пахомова и др.:

> ***О Суламифь**, тот день, когда ты сделаешься моей женой и царицей, будет самым счастливым для моего сердца.*

В этом примере «о» ведь тоже стоит **НЕ перед риторическим обращением**… Но запятой от него не отделяется.

Answer (score 0):

О выделяется запятой, если заменимо на И, потому что тогда стоит обращение далее.

> На серые камни ложилась дремота,
> Но прялкой вилась городская забота.
> Где храмы подъяты и выступы круты,
> — Я видел вас, женщины в темных одеждах,
> С молитвой в глазах и с изменой в надеждах 
> — О, женщины помнят такие минуты!
> Сходились, считая ступень за ступенью,
> И вновь расходились, томимые тенью, 
> Сияя очами, сливаясь с тенями…
> О, город! О, ветер! О, снежные бури!
> О, бездна разорванной в клочья лазури!
> Я здесь! Я невинен! Я с вами! Я с вами! Декабрь 1906

И женщины помнят такие минуты, и город, и ветер, и снежные бури, и бездна разорванной в клочья лазури.

То есть тут не обращение, а запятая обусловлена междометьем о.

А "о недостойный" - явно О входит в состав обращения к недостойному, придавая эмоциональный окрас, запятая очевидно не нужна, а И не заменимо. Акцент идет на слово недостойный - о недостОйный!

У Блога же не так, него акцент на О.

О, недостойный! - тоже можно, но смысл меняется и на И не заменишь, однако. Так что это скорее авторский знак, чем какой-то очевидный.

Comment: Нельзя так обращаться: О недостойный! Надо говорить: О достойнейший! //А в риторике все можно.  Если чувства выражаете, то междометие. // У Блока не надо списывать))

Comment: @Sharon почему нельзя?

Comment: Вы же не скажете так:  О обманщик, опять мне книгу не принес!

Comment: @Sharon и обманщик опять мне книгу принес.

Comment: Ах ты обманщик! Так говорят.  А вы приведите проверенные примеры из классики с таким обращением (о презренный и т. д.), тогда я поверю.  А пока вы, может, обманщик.

Comment: @Sharon Ах ты, обмащик.

Comment: Sharon: «_Нельзя так обращаться: О недостойный! Надо говорить: О достойнейший!_»; «_Вы же не скажете так: О обманщик, опять мне книгу не принес!_» === Из сказок «Тысяча и одна ночь»: _**О обманщик**, — сказал царь, — что такое деньги, раз пришла его поклажа?_ 

Comment: Это ошибка.  Там даже восклицательный знак не написали. А кто, кстати, Пушкина подправил и запятую поставил?

Comment: Просто с Ах не обращаются, а с О обращаются. Ах, Шарон. О Шарон!

Comment: "Вправду ополоумел! Ах ты вражина!"  Без запятой.  — Ах ты окаянный! — кричал есаул. — что ты, над нами смеешься, что ли?  И везде одна ругань.

Comment: @Sharon ну это уже совсем ругань пошла), поэтому тут лучше запятую. А "о недостойный" - это же классика, "о смерд", "о раб" - эпитеты доминирования.  А "ах вражина, ах проститутка" - это уже ругань. деклассирующие утверждения.

Comment: Что же вашу классику на запятую поменяли?

Comment: Sharon: «_Это ошибка. Там даже восклицательный знак не написали_». === По-моему, **вопросительного** знака в конце того предложения вполне хватает для прочтения его с соответствующей интонацией.

Comment: @Sharon в общем ладно, разные фразы по звучанию)