# Какое значение имеет слово "ну" в сочетании "ну и ну"?

Tags: лексика, фразеология, семантика

1. Это известное выражение, которое есть **в словаре:**

Современный толковый словарь русского языка **Ефремовой**: ***Ну и ну́***, межд. разг. Возглас, выражающий **удивление, неодобрение**.

Пример: *Мать внимательно поглядела на сына и только головой покачала, мол **ну и ну**, дожили.*

2. В то же время хотелось бы знать, как образовано это сочетание и какое значение имеет **само слово *НУ***. По словарю это **частица и междометие**, но какой именно **смысл** мы вкладываем в это слово.

Можно считать, что это побуждение, **призыв к действию** (ну, поехали!), но в сочетании "ну и ну" такой смысл **не просматривается** очевидно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть интересующее нас междометие ***Ну***, обособляемое в предложении со значением разочарованности (*Ну, мы это переживём*); частица ***Ну и***, употребляемая для придачи доли эмоции в начале или конце основного высказываниия (*Ну и забот у вас...*); есть её вариант с запятой внутри ***Ну, ...и*** (*Ну, он и мерзавец!*); есть устойчивое, обособляемое в предложении и отделяемое междометие ***Ну и ну*** (*Я такое сказал? Ну и ну!*), которое само по себе являет только чистую эмоцию — знак толи восторга, толи досады, толи изумления, толи прозрения. Чаще эти эмоции не направляются вовне: «*Ну и ну, никогда бы не подумал!*»

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ и за интерес к теме. Находясь под впечатлением от недавнего обсуждения междометия О, я задумалась о значении остальных междометий...  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476604/О-частица-или-междометие

Comment: Sharon, Ну и ну! Вопрос-то более обстоятельного и доказательного ответа заслуживает...

Comment: За интерес!  Мне отдельные звуки очень интересны, но не другим. У нас любят практические вопросы: про буквы, цифры, запятые и пробелы. Главное –  как написать))

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что все междометия можно **разделить** на отдельные (гласные и согласные) **звуки** и подумать об их **значении**.

1. Вероятно, главным значением ***НУ*** является **удивление**. Такое же значение и у междометия ***О***. Что у них **общего?**

По участию губ гласные делятся на огубленные (или **лабиализованные** – от лат. labium «губа») и неогубленные (**нелабиализованные**). К лабиализованным относят звуки [о] и [у], причем степень лабиализованности [у] выше. Возможно,  это как-то связано с **мимикой** лица.

2. Междометие ***О*** — звук  **особенный**,  сакральный, в нем чувствуется **возвышенность**.  Протяженный звук выражает чувство непосредственно, а краткая частица-междометие  О тоже, как я думаю, соединяется **не с каждым словом.** Странно звучит сочетание ***«о презренный»*** , лучше сказать ***«о великий».***
3. Согласный Н — носовой, вот его полная характеристика: носовой, смычно-проходной, **сонорный,** **язычно-зубной** звук. При произнесении звука [n] губы находятся в **нейтральной** позиции и принимают положение последующего гласного звука.

Что означают носовой звук  ***Н*** — пока у меня нет предположений, но что-то означает.  Он используется в словах ***на, но, не, нет.***

4. **Протяженность** гласного звука — это тоже **показатель**  значения. В кратких словах ***но, ну*** удивление как бы переходит **в нетерпение**: в чем дело, почему остановились и не двигаемся дальше?
5. Что означает ***«ну и ну»?***  Вероятно, это соединение двух ***НУ*** и **усиление** удивления.

P. S. Скорее всего, есть какие-то **исследования** на эту тему, но **все сказанное** здесь — это мое собственное восприятие слов, если что))